# Swift passing element as variable

Tags: javascript, ios, swift

In javascript I know i can something like the following:

```
var foo = '';

function changeVariable(variable, data){
  this[variable] = data;
}

changeVariable("foo", "bar");
```

Is there away I can do this in swift?

```
func toggleFadeIn (element: String, active: Bool)
{
    if(!active){
        self.element.alpha = 0;
        self.element.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 25)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is a dynamic language that has the facilities of modifying objects in such a way at runtime.

Static languages (like Swift, Java, C#, and many others) require a reflection library to implement such behaviour. Unfortunately, Swift has a really limited reflection capability ([`Mirror`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/mirror)) and doesn't have the ability to modify object/struct members by their `String` names, yet.

If you elaborate on what exactly you were trying to achieve with this, we would be better able to suggest solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I was trying to create a helper function to set an element to a hidden state that i can then again reanimate calling the same helper function as active. This is how i would do it in javascript so i wouldn't have to set ever element I want by hand.

Comment: I would call the function with the element string and set to true or false to toggle the alpha and transform

Comment: Doing that wouldn't be advisable, even in JavaScript. Why would you use the string name "elementOfInterest" instead of just passing in the reference to `object.elementOfInterest`?

Comment: Your answer is correct, but I dispute your "unfortunately" and your "yet". Swift is strictly typed and the language designers deliberately designed it not to support this sort of loosey-goosey dynamic behavior. It can't be validated at compile time, so if you make a mistake, your program either crashes or doesn't do what it was supposed to do.

Comment: @DuncanC No, they do have the intention to implement a full-featured reflection API. In fact, a lot of the metadata necessary for that to happen already exists in compiled swift modules, today. They're currently only used by Xcode, Instruments and other related tools for debugging and profiling.

Comment: Okay so hard code the attributes is the way to go here then?

Comment: @DuncanC I agree that using such a library for this "loosey-goosey dynamic behavior" is less than desirable. But having reflection support is absolutely key to ORM and serialization libraries. Think of how many less bullshit JSON  force-casting/unwrapping related questions would vanish if there was a reflection system that implemented automatic JSON deserialization.

Comment: @RickiMoore Absolutely. There's absolutely no reason to be using string names. It would be unsafe (the compiler can't verify that the string represent real properties), slow, and completely unnecessary complexity.

Comment: @DuncanC And to add on to my comment, the reason they haven't done it yet is because a lot of the metadata isn't finalized yet (since the ABI isn't stable yet).

Comment: @Alexander, fair enough. There are good reasons for language support for reflection, but this isn't one of those reasons. We need a clean, Swift equivalent of `NSCoding`

Comment: @DuncanC Yep, and it's coming in the form of `Codeable` in Swift 4 :D

Answer (score -2):

What you describe IS possible using KVO on `NSObjects`. It relies on Objective-C dynamic messaging, but it does work. Take a look a the function `setValue:forKey:`, as documented in [**Apple's Key Value Programming Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/).

Note that this is decidedly un-swiftlike, and not recommended.

Comment: Note to OP: possible ≠ advisable

Comment: As Alexander says, this isn't recommended.